# How do I implement a canvas inside a class which extends ViewGroup?

Tags: java, android

I want to draw graphics inside a custom view, and I decided that this customview will have to extend ViewGroup instead of View, because I will also place buttons and images inside the screen.

But the thing is, viewgroup clearly is very different from view, and there are tons of tuts on canvas + view combination but none, I repeat, none on canvas + ViewGroup combination, and I'm turning to SO for help!

What are the general steps? What are the pitfalls which I should avoid?

Do I have to implement my canvas inside a view inside a ViewGroup?

Comment: override draw/ dispatchDraw methods

Comment: @pskink is that similar in nature to overriding onDraw in view??